# requesting a template to the domain

Tags: php, html, templates, content-management-system

I'm create a **cms**. I have a following issue in my head.My template installed directory is this

```
pard_site/view/index.php
```

And at the movement there is a default template.my root contain 14 folder and index.php also like bellow

```
pard_admin
pard_images
...........
pard......
..........
pard_site ( pard_site/view/index.php)
.htaccess
index.php
```

**Root means the domain**.So how would i requesting my template to the domain using php?

Comment: `include()`? Not sure what you mean. Can you clarify what your question is about?

Comment: Joomla,wp In those cms.we can installed bew template to the site.and when we requesting our domain we can see our template.so how would i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If your template has got 3 files header.php, content.php and footer.php, you have to put them in "template" directory. Also, in the root dir you can create some files which include the template form otterresti dir.

It's an example.